# Enable port-forwarding (SSH): ssh: connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I want to make a remote connection using ssh to my pc when I'm not home.

Let's say X.X.X.X written in title is my global ip router.

I've done the following steps:

- Install openssh-server on my home pc.
- Enable router port-forwarding on port 22. I've checked before deploy ssh server that router enabled port-forwarding listening on that port with netcat and test with this online tool [open-port-check-tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). I guess that sends some packets to my global ip in order to test wheter port is open or not.
- Run the sshd deamon so port 22 is now being listened. I've checked this running `sudo ss -nlput | grep 22` and `sudo service sshd status`.
- Check if computer firewall was blocking ssh packets: I list my iptables configuration and I was enabling all input, output, and forwarding.  `sudo iptables -L`:

  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

As far as I'm concerned I should be able to make an ssh connection from anywhere to my home pc using global ip router and choosing my linux user called 'user' as follows: ssh user@X.X.X.X

Did I miss any step?

Comment: Have you tried creating a allow any to test? `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @A.B but if enable port 22 on my router I can ping my global ip (the test i did with netcat) otherwise I can't. Is it still related to router issues?

Comment: @A.B If I understand well you want me to check what packets are going through my router? Okey, I have tried using wireshark to see ssh packets and when I try to connect with ssh I get the classic error message "...connection refused" but I have no trace from any packet in wireshark. I have trying connecting another server (not my home pc) using ssh and I could see the trace of ssh packages so I think that I'm doing it correctly